What is the invalidAfter function in the token Policy?
I’m looking to play around with creating a native token.
When building out the token policy script, I’m looking to add a time-lock with the invalidAfter function but I’m unable to find a source in the official Cardano documentation with the invalidAfter keyword. I do see the “after” and “before” keywords however..
I'm looking to generate a policy similar to this one:
{
   all: [
      {
         pubKeyHash: "721d21508287404332f35f43054bhc223g9ab3z73ad8333c160039f0"
      },
      {
         invalidAfter: 49422890
      }
   ]
}

Would anyone be able to shed some light on this for me, or point me to the right direction?
Thanks all!
